# Integrate Umbraco in an MVC and not the other way round

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have little to no experience in Umbraco, but it has been suggested to me as I have been asked to integrate a CMS system within my existing application.  I have gone through some videos how to use Umbraco and done well so far. The problem is as follows. I have an existing MVC application with custom routing but both use the same database and dll. Example: [www.ngomalta.com](http://www.ngomalta.com) and [animalguardians.ngomalta.com](http://animalguardians.ngomalta.com)

Both have same interface, but with custom routing I can load some pages on a subdomain but not in the other. I would like to implement the same 'logic' using Umbraco. That is, I want both sites to have access to umbraco but they would have different content. Please note that it may be that I would have other sub domains in the future such as tomasina.ngomalta.com, and thus I would like scalability.

I have had a look on the net and other answers. However the solutions that I found are vice versa! What I mean is, that solutions given assume that you have an Umbraco site and you want to add an MVC controller.  My situation is the opposite, I have the MVC and would like to add Umbraco views. Thus I want to make Umbraco compatabile with MVC and not design an MVC solution to be compatible/integrated with Umbraco.

Currently I have implemented a class that Inherits UmbracoApplication + WebBootManagerand and which overrides the Complete function.  I have also tried  to use my existing custom routing class (that inherits from [RouteBase]).  It looks as if they work.. but the CSS styles and javascripts are not sort of routed or I don't know.  They just aren't sent to the client. hence only the HTML is sent for both Umbraco page and my existing MVC views

First of all, is my idea with Umbraco possible?

If yes,  can someone guide me some site that implements Umbraco in an existing (LIVE) MVC application and not the other way round?  many of the tutorials that exist always start from a blank MVC application and build on that.  I don't want such tutorials.  I need a tutorial, that shows how an existing MVC application with already-existing-controllers that tries to integrate Umbraco.

Thanks for reading people..
!

Comment: From what I have seen with Umbraco this is not possible out the box because Umbraco defines the routes. It may be possible with some hackery, because for example you can intercept requests by doing things like RouteHijacking, but these still work within an Umbraco framework. I don't expect you will find much in the way of what you are looking for because that's not really how Umbraco is used.

Comment: thanks.. I have managed something with route hijacking but it is not resolving the CSS and JS files correctly. Obviously I'm doing something wrong or need to polish it up. But since it is a small project it is more worth while to adapt my project to umbraco than keep fiddling around to make it the other round.
I wonder how, people who have a large, establish ASP .NET project running who want to add a couple of CMS pages do that with Umbraco.  Do they have to change everything to make it Umbraco-compatible?

Comment: That is a question I am currently struggling with as well! ;D